# Gmail policy for https images with missing SSL certificate

Tags: image, email, ssl, gmail

I'm working on an EN store for a client, which is on a separate domain from the original language (and this second domain does not - yet - have a valid SSL certificate).

When sending emails, the images are visible on yahoo. However, on gmail they are missing (404). The image URLs generated by gmail look like this:

> https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/A_CCC-sd3OA3rSPyxMwmVMzZQrdMke4_UkaB1B7QZO_J-#https://www.bla-bla.com/images/en/discounts.jpg

`https://www.bla-bla.com/images/en/discounts.jpg` works fine if copied in a separate tab, but not in gmail.

Is it possible that the images are not shown because of the missing SSL certificate ? I'm not sure where I can find some documentation on these rules.

Comment: this also happened to me, did you get the solution ?